# Error of missed header when using the cppfront compiler

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++

I'm trying to test the new experimental syntax called "CPP2.0" presented by Herb Sutter in the CppCon 2022 [Can C++ be 10x Simpler & Safer? - Herb Sutter](https://youtu.be/ELeZAKCN4tY), but I'm having error of a header not located, these are my steps until now:

I cloned the cppfront project: `git clone git@github.com:hsutter/cppfront.git` from the folder `source` I build the `cppfront` using the command:

```bash
g++-12 cppfront.cpp -std=c++20 -o cppfront
```

As instructed in the **README**.

This successfully generates the `cppfront` bin file.

Then with this `hello.cpp2` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

name: () -> std::string = {
    s: std::string = "world";
    decorate(s);
    return s;
}

decorate: (inout s: std::string) = {
    s = "[" + s + "]";
}

auto main() -> int {
    //name();
    std::cout << "Hello" << name() << "\n";
}
```

I tried to compile using the **cppfront** with the command:

```bash
./cppfront hello.cpp2
```

And I have the return of compilation:

```
hello.cpp2... ok (mixed Cpp1/Cpp2, Cpp2 code passes safety checks)
```

What indicates that the conversion from "cpp2.0" to "cpp1.0" was done successfully, then in the moment of compile the `hello.cpp` standard cpp I got the error:

```
g++-12 hello.cpp -std=c++20

hello.cpp:6:10: fatal error: cpp2util.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: that file is shipped with cppfront. Use `-Iinclude` to tell g++ where to look.

Comment: @Botje I tried to do it but a bunch of errors occurs, but it compiles perfectly normal when I copy the header file to the location of my `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was wrong, looks like the header was inside the cppfront source code:

```
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── include
│   └── **cpp2util.h**
.
.
.
. (continues)
```

So I just copy this header to the location where my `hello.cpp` was and it compiles and works normally.